# Getting the total sum of data in a particular timeframe

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables called listings and logs with the following headers:

Logs Table:

[image]

The logs table makes a new record every status change made and passes the current timestamp as the logtime, and the listings table changes/updates the status and updates its update_date. Now to get the total listings as of today I'm using the following statement:

```
SELECT SUM(status = 'D') AS draft, SUM(status = 'N') AS action, SUM(status = 'Y') AS publish 
FROM `crm_listings` where updated_date between '2021-05-29' and '2021-05-29'
```

Basically I want to return all the records that happened between a particular timeframe.

**Note**: Refno isn't unique in my logs table since a product with the same refno can be marked as publish 1 day and unpublish another, but it is unique in my listings table.

Comment: `updated_date between '2021-05-29' and '2021-05-29'` only returns the records which happen to be updated on the date, but records updated in previous dates and never changes and records updated again in later dates are not included.

Comment: @ProGu yea basically with the above example, if suppose yesterday was '2021-05-29' and I want to retrieve my total for that date which is 10 in this case, I have to basically find out from my logs table for any statuses that were changed to action in the timeframe between today and yesterday which will be 15(todays total)-5(changed to action) and return that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose all `listing` entries appear in the `log_table`, even if it was created but no status change since then.

So it needs to lookup the log table only for the record with latest logtime up to the query date for each `refno`, the `status_to` for the selected record is the standing status for the date.

To archive this, sort the log_table by refno and logtime in descending order and find the first record for each refno.

```
SELECT SUM(status_to = 'Action'), SUM(status_to = 'Publish') FROM (
    SELECT refno, status_to, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY refno ORDER BY logtime DESC) AS RN
    FROM log_table 
    WHERE logtime <= '2021-05-29 23:59:59'
) r
WHERE r.RN = 1
```

or this for older MySQL servers

```
SELECT SUM(status_to = 'Action'), SUM(status_to = 'Publish') FROM (
    SELECT refno, status_to, CASE WHEN @RF != refno THEN @RN := 1 ELSE @RN := @RN + 1 END AS RN, @RF := refno
    FROM log_table 
    JOIN ( SELECT @RN := 0 , @RF := '' ) f
    WHERE logtime <= '2021-05-29 23:59:59'
    ORDER BY refno ASC, logtime DESC
) r
WHERE r.RN = 1
```

If log_table is huge and this query is important, do consider to create another table to store such daily statistics.

Comment: This gives this error: Can't group on 'SUM(status_to = 'Action')'

Comment: Sorry, remove `GROUP BY 1`

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238098/doubt-clearing Could you join this room for clearing a few things

Comment: Okay so now based on your new query which worked how do I show the sum?

Comment: wrap the query with another select, e.g. `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Action' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Actions FROM ( ... ) v`

Comment: Okay and could you also look at this question which is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69565575/subtracting-or-adding-data-based-on-logtime-of-another-table?noredirect=1#comment122959924_69565575